# How do I fix ' ValueError: callback must be a callable, got None' on schedule Kivy.clock callback function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a function that uses the `plyer.facades.Wifi` library to check the wifi status.  The function changes a `BooleanProperty` variable `is_wifi` to `True` or `False` depending on the status of the wifi.  The `BooleanProperty` variable is binded in the `Kv-Language` script to an `ActionLabel` which changes the image depending on the status.
The function is then scheduled using Kivy's `Clock.schedule_interval()`.

#### Problem

The main problem is I am getting a `ValueError: callback must be a callable, got None` when I schedule the function callback.

I have tried:
1] scheduling the function on initialisation.
2] Calling the scheduling event after initialisation when the user sign in.

#### Code sample of the imports and function that is called

```
from plyer import wifi
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock

class TheLogger(FloatLayout):
    is_wifi = BooleanProperty(wifi.is_enabled())
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def wifi_is_enabled(self): #Scheduling a callback of this function
        print('checking connection')
        try:
            if wifi.is_enabled():
                self.is_wifi = True
            else:
                self.is_wifi = False
        except OSError:
            pass
class LoginApp(App):
    title = 'Login'
    def build(self):
        self.icon = 'sign_in_5243564.png'
        rt = TheLogger()
        Clock.schedule_interval(rt.wifi_is_enabled(), 0.5) #scheduling callback of wifi_is_enabled() function
        return rt
```

#### Kivy language sample that shows binding on the ActionLabel

```
Builder.load_string('''
<TheLogger>:
    un_input: user_in
    ScreenManager:
        id: _screen_manager
        Screen:
            name: 'choice'
            ActionBar:
                pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'right': 1}
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: (0,0.4,0.51,1)
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                ActionView:
                    use_separator: True
                    ActionPrevious:
                        title: "Sign Out"
                        with_previous: True
                        app_icon: ''
                        color: (1,1,1,1)
                        on_release: app.root.sign_out()
                    ActionLabel: #ActionLabel source with If else block code on callback
                        text: ''
                        Image:
                            source: 'green_wifi_connected_5456.png' if root.is_wifi else 'red_ic_signal_wifi_off_48px_352130.png'
                            center_y: self.parent.center_y
                            center_x: self.parent.center_x
                            size: self.parent.width /1, self.parent.height/ 1
                            allow_stretch: True
''')
```

#### Expected result

I want the function to schedule a callback without errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Clock.schedule_interval(rt.wifi_is_enabled(), 0.5)
```

This code is equivalent to:

```
callback = rt.wifi_is_enabled()
Clock.schedule_interval(callback, 0.5)
```

Do you see the problem now? The value of callback is None, which is what you try to schedule.

You need to schedule the function itself, not its return value:

```
Clock.schedule_interval(rt.wifi_is_enabled, 0.5)
```

Note that the function will automatically receive a positional argument containing the time since last run/scheduled. Your function will need to accept this argument, even if it ignores it.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved it.  I removed the parenthesis, added the root class to super and gave the function the second argument ```*args```. Now it works and schedules the function callback. I am always learning new intricate nuances of the Python language.  Thanks again!

Comment: I litteraly made the exact same mistake, found this searching google, and solved it in a total of less than a minute. Thanks